# Is there a way to create a data collector set from a C program?

Tags: c++, c, windows, performance

In windows performance monitor there is an option to create **Data collector sets**. Now is there any way to create a data collector set programmatically and read the log later from a C or C++ program(is there any specific api that i can do this)?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509354%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "Performance Logs and Alerts" (PLA) of Microsoft.
With PLA you can create your own Data collector sets and work with existing ones. Collected Data may be saved in a .csv file, which can be evaluated with c or C++ algorithms